# What should I have to change in that function to get the 0.00 like effect?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, numbers, decimal

To get the fraction point value up to two decimal points, I use this function:

```
double roundTwoDecimals(double d) {             
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("##.##");         
    return Double.valueOf(twoDForm.format(d));
```

But while there is a value like "5.50", then with this function I got only "5.5".
Instead of that, I want to get the 5.50 with the above function.  So what should I have to change?

Please give me the updated function or any suggestions to change the output like "0.00".

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? Are you actually trying to round the number and return a double? Or are you simply wanting to format the number for display? You're *always* going to get a non-formatted number returned from this method because `double`s won't preserve the leading/trailing zeroes you format the number to.

Comment: I am just want to get the fraction value of the double value but it should be of two decimal point. I am not going to round the value. ok.

Comment: @iDroid Explorer - here all users told the same things.

Comment: I simply want to improve my function to give me the desired result and that i want from the suknic result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works fine for rounding numbers to 2 digits. But you will lose trailing zeros, because numeric variables (double, float, ...) do not store any formating information.

If you want to see trailing zeros (like 5.50) you have to format the numbers on output:

```
DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");         
System.out.println(twoDForm.format(d));
```

Answer (score 2):

[Use the format](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
new DecimalFormat("#0.00")
```

When you use `#`, zero values display as absent. Using a `0` will ensure that either a digit or a 0 is displayed.

Comment: I have change the function with this formate but still i got the same result.

Answer (score 1):

DecimalFormat.format returns a String (not a StringBuffer), which you are then getting the Double.valueOf(...).  You then return the double value, which I assume when you print it uses it's own toString() to be displayed.  You need to run the DecimalFormat.format on the double value returned.

Comment: [`DecimalFormat#format(double)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format(double)) doesn't return a `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @RobHruska:  Thanks for putting me right.  I didn't check java 7.  In the pages I looked at under Android(http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) and java 6(http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) I didn't see this method. I should have searched further.

Comment: I dont want to get the string. I have just mention "" to differentiate the value.

Comment: @mikey - The Android javadocs are essentially the same. `DecimalFormat` inherits from `NumberFormat`, which defines [`format(double)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format(double)).